# Python CLick: AttributeError: module 'click' has no attribute 'hidden'

Tags: python, attributes, python-click

I am creating a terminal client using the `click` library. This is my `cli.py` -

```py
import os
import sys
import click
import importlib
from ogcmaps.utils import commands

class Context(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.pretty_print = False

pass_context = click.make_pass_decorator(Context, ensure=True)


class OGCmapsCLI(click.MultiCommand):

    def list_commands(self, ctx):
        rv = []
        for func in dir(commands):
            if not func.startswith("__"):
                rv.append(func)
        rv.sort()
        return rv

    def get_command(self, ctx, name):
        try:
            mod = importlib.import_module('ogcmaps.utils.commands')
            return getattr(mod, name)
        except ImportError:
            return


@click.command(cls=OGCmapsCLI)
@click.option('-p', '--prettify', is_flag=True,
              help='Pretty print the JSON response')
@pass_context
def cli(ctx, prettify):
    """
    Keep and view shell commands in terminal only.
    Read more at https://github.com/orkohunter/keep
    """
    ctx.pretty_print = prettify
```

I get the following error when running the python client -

```bash
AttributeError: module 'click' has no attribute 'hidden'
```

My click commands are located in utils/commands.py. The error goes away if I `return getattr(mod, "my_command_name")` instead of `return getattr(mod, name)`.

Stacktrace -

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ogcmaps", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1126, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1050, in main
    with self.make_context(prog_name, args, **extra) as ctx:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 912, in make_context
    self.parse_args(ctx, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1610, in parse_args
    echo(ctx.get_help(), color=ctx.color)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 693, in get_help
    return self.command.get_help(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1293, in get_help
    self.format_help(ctx, formatter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1324, in format_help
    self.format_options(ctx, formatter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1522, in format_options
    self.format_commands(ctx, formatter)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1590, in format_commands
    if cmd.hidden:
AttributeError: module 'click' has no attribute 'hidden'
```

Comment: I strongly suggest sharing the _full_ stacktrace. The error on its own is rarely that useful. We don't even know what line the error came from. I'm assuming it's the `return getattr(...)` line?

Comment: Yes. `getattr()` is not causing an issue as I used a string with it and it worked fine. I have updated the question with the stacktrace.